# BeautifulSoup Python script no longer working for mining a simple field

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

The script used to work, but no longer and I can't figure out why. I am trying to go to the link and extract/print the religion field. Using firebug, the religion field entry is within the 'tbody' then 'td' tag-structure. But now the script find "none" when searching for these tags. And I also look at the lxml by 'print Soup_FamSearch' and I couldn't see any 'tbody' and 'td' tags appeared on firebug.

Please let me know what I am missing?

```
import urllib2
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from unicodedata import normalize

FamSearchURL = 'https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/KH21-211'
OpenFamSearchURL = urllib2.urlopen(FamSearchURL)
Soup_FamSearch = BeautifulSoup(OpenFamSearchURL, 'lxml')
OpenFamSearchURL.close()

tbodyTags = Soup_FamSearch.find('tbody')
trTags = tbodyTags.find_all('tr', class_='result-item ')

for trTags in trTags:
    tdTags_label = trTag.find('td', class_='result-label ')
    if tdTags_label:
        tdTags_label_string = tdTags_label.get_text(strip=True)

        if tdTags_label_string == 'Religion: ':
            print trTags.find('td', class_='result-value ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `Religion:` label [by text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) and get the [next `td` sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.find(text='Religion:').parent.find_next_sibling('td').get_text(strip=True)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> response = requests.get('https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/KH21-211')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
>>> 
>>> soup.find(text='Religion:').parent.find_next_sibling('td').get_text(strip=True)
Methodist
```

---

Then, you can make a nice reusable function and reuse:

```
def get_field_value(soup, field):
    return soup.find(text='%s:' % field).parent.find_next_sibling('td').get_text(strip=True)

print get_field_value(soup, 'Religion')
print get_field_value(soup, 'Nationality')
print get_field_value(soup, 'Birthplace')
```

Prints:

```
Methodist
Canadian
Ontario
```

Comment: I never knew this neat way to find tags, thanks. Though, When I tried the demo code, I got this 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'' which is also what I got from the original program.

Comment: @KubiK888 thanks, are you sure you have `lxml` installed? (I can reproduce the error if `lxml` is not installed, getting `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?` on the console and then `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'` errors)

Comment: You are right. But it's kind of interesting and strange. I made sure I have the lxml module installed before by re-running "pip install lxml", the installation seems to work but the script gives the same error. Only if I download and install the lxml module from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, does it seem to to work. Thanks.